# Vim: Automatically leave insert mode after some time

Tags: vim

I want to make Vim leave `Insert` mode automagically after some time (15 seconds). Here is what I've got in
my `.vimrc`:

```
" set 'updatetime' to 15 seconds when in insert mode
au InsertEnter * let updaterestore = &updatetime | set updatetime=15000
au InsertLeave * let &updatetime = updaterestore

" automatically leave insert mode after 'updatetime' milliseconds of inaction
au CursorHoldI * stopinsert
```

I am using this snippet in MacVim, and it doesn't work. When I enter `Insert` mode, and I don't do anything,
Vim leaves insert mode after 15 seconds. However, if I press `Enter` or `Backspace`, or if I enter `Insert` mode
using `o`/`O`, then Vim leaves `Insert` mode straight away, and at that point, even if I enter `Insert` mode using `i`
Vim goes back to `Normal` mode straight away.

I installed MacVim using Homebrew on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Any ideas why this is not working please?

**Edit:** Here is my MacVim version with all the flags:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 29 2013 02:17:27)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-22
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fullscreen      -mzscheme        +textobjects
+cindent         -gettext         +netbeans_intg   +title
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +odbeditor       +toolbar
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +transparency
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax          
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: cc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1  
Linking: cc   -L.   -L.    -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -framework Python  -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Tcl -framework CoreFoundation -framework Ruby
```

Comment: I can't replicate the behavior you are talking about

Comment: I found someone on IRC that could, and another person that couldn't... I don't understand, this issue looks a bit random to me...

Comment: I'm using 7.4.22 for macvim and 7.4.35 for terminal.

Comment: I am using MacVim 7.3 (66), maybe that's why... is 7.4 available via Homebrew or I need to compile it from source?

Comment: No idea if its available from homebrew. You can always download it from the macvim website if it isn't

Comment: I just upgraded to MacVim 7.4.71 and it didn't fix the problem...

Comment: You should fix your equal signs: let foo = 1 and set bar=1.

Comment: @romainl Done, but that didn't fix the problem

Comment: Do you have any insert mode mappings for Enter / Backspace? These (plugins) could cause this. `:verbose imap <CR>`?

Comment: @IngoKarkat That's a good question. Here is my full `.vimrc`: https://gist.github.com/AzizLight/6744519 I use quite a lot of plugins, and the following setting: `set backspace=indent,eol,start`. I don't know if that is the problem, will investigate.

Comment: Your vimrc is really big, you should try to bisect it to isolate a possible mapping issue and probably do the same with your 50 or so (freaking) plugins.

Comment: what do you mean bisect it ? :S

Comment: Basically, you disable (comment out) half of your vimrc to see if you still have the problem, then test it with the other half.  If only one of those halves has the problem, you split _it_ in half and repeat till you find the offending setting/plugin/etc.

Comment: Actually, though, in this case you should probably start with nothing in your vimrc but those lines you quoted above, to see if it works with a minimal setup, and go from there.

Comment: @abjuk or @romainl could one of you post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it please? I found the source of the error. It was the `HiCursorWords` plugin, which I forked and pathed. Now all is working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @romainl commented, the fastest way to narrow down a problem like this is bisection.  Basically, you disable (comment out) half of your vimrc to see if you still have the problem, then test it with the other half. If only one of those halves has the problem, you split *it* in half and repeat until you find the offending setting/plugin/etc.

For sanity's sake, with an issue like this it's also a good idea to start by testing a minimal setup (i.e. a vimrc with just the lines quoted in the problem description) to make sure it's not a wild goose chase.